# NGINX Setup to Match Proxy Middleware Configuration

Tags: reactjs, nginx, proxy, routes, reverse-proxy

I have the following setupProxy.js class that configures redirection for api calls to my server.

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require("http-proxy-middleware");

module.exports = function (app) {
    app.use(
        "/api/tours",
        createProxyMiddleware({
            target: "http://localhost:5000", 
            changeOrigin: true,
        })
    );
};
```

My App.js looks like

```
const App = () => {

    const { userDetails } = useContext(AuthContext);
    const { colorMode } = useContext(ColorModeContext);

    let currentTheme = React.useMemo(() =>
        createTheme(deepmerge(getDesignTokens(colorMode)), getThemedComponents(colorMode)),
        [colorMode]
    );
    currentTheme = responsiveFontSizes(currentTheme);
 
    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={currentTheme}>
            <CssBaseline />
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <AuthRoute exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
                    <AuthRoute path="/home" component={HomePage} />
                    <Route path="/public/:id" component={PlayerPage} />
                    <AuthRoute path="/tours/:id" component={PlayerPage} />
                    <Route path="/login">
                        {userDetails == null ? <LoginPage /> : <Redirect to="/home" />}
                    </Route>
                    <Route component={FourOhFour} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
};
export default App;
```

and I can navigate to my `PlayerPage` using a url like

> localhost:3000/tours/eef67wsrr899iop009

This loads fine with the PlayerPage looking like

```
const PlayerPage = () => {

    const history = useHistory();

    const { id } = useParams();
    const mode = LocalStorgaeCache.getItem(APP_COLOR_MODE_KEY);
    const theme = createTheme(deepmerge(getDesignTokens(mode), getThemedComponents(mode)));
    
    const { userDetails } = useContext(AuthContext);
    const { tourDetails, isLoading: isLoadingTour, dispatch } = useContext(TourContext);

    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [showTagInfo, setTagId] = useState(0);
    const [tagInfoWindowVisible, showTagInfoWindow] = useState(false);
    const [results] = useState([]);
    const [setTour] = useState();
    const showTagging = useRef(false);
    const [showScan, setShowScan] = useState(false);
    const [addTag, setAddTag] = useState(false);
    const [tagging, setTagging] = useState(false);
    const [myPos, setPos] = useState([]);

    const myLayer = useRef(0);
    const tagEditing = useRef(false);
    const refreshTag = useRef(false);
    const [myTagNumber, setTagNumber] = useState(0);

    const [showPosInfo, setPosInfo] = useState('');
    const [snackMessage, setSnackMessage] = useState('');
    const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useState(false);

    const [myTags, setTags] = useState([{}]);
    const [watermark, setWatermark] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            dispatch(clearLoadedTour());
        };
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        setIsMobile(navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad)|(iPhone)|(iPod)|(android)|(webOS)/i));

        const actualLoad = async () => {

            if (userDetails == null) { 
                history.push("/login");
            }
            await getTour(userDetails, id, dispatch);
            setLoading(false);
        };

        if (tourDetails == null) {
            actualLoad();
        }
        else {
            const simulateLoad = async () => {
                await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 1000));
                setLoading(false);
            };
            simulateLoad();
        }
    }, [dispatch, history, id, tourDetails, userDetails]);

    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <Fragment>
                <Backdrop
                    sx={{ color: "white", zIndex: (theme) => theme.zIndex.drawer + 1 }}
                    open={loading}>
                    <CircularProgress color="inherit" />
                </Backdrop>
                { tourDetails != null ? (
                <div>
                    {!watermark && <Watermark />}
                    <SimpleSnackBar snackMessage={snackMessage} />
                    <InfoCard
                        tagEditing={tagEditing}
                        setTagging={setTagging}
                        setShow={showTagInfoWindow}
                        refreshTag={refreshTag}
                        setTour={setTour}
                        setShowScan={setShowScan}
                        results={results}
                        tagNumber={myTagNumber}
                        tags={myTags}
                        tour={tourDetails?.MyappTour}
                        pos={myPos}
                        setAddTag={setAddTag}
                        cb={showPosInfo}
                        st={showTagInfo}
                    />
                    {tagInfoWindowVisible && (
                        <MediaCard
                            tagEditing={tagEditing}
                            tagId={showTagInfo}
                            setShow={showTagInfoWindow}
                        />
                    )}
                    <Player
                        token={tourDetails?.azureServiceSasToken}
                        tour={tourDetails?.MyappTour}
                        account={tourDetails?.azureStorageUri}
                        setSnackMessage={setSnackMessage}
                        layer={myLayer}
                        tagging2={tagging}
                        refreshTag={refreshTag}
                        setTagId={setTagId}
                        showTagInfoWindow={showTagInfoWindow}
                        setPosInfo={setPosInfo}
                        setLoading={setLoading}
                        setNewTagPosition={setPos}
                        tagEditing={tagEditing}
                    />
                </div>
                ) : ( <></> ) }
            </Fragment>
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
};
export default PlayerPage;
```

The problem is, when I deploy this client and server with NGINX as the reverse-proxy and load balancer, the

> myapp.com/tours/eef67wsrr899iop009

does not work, it merely gives a blank page and the browser console window is showing

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
> Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.

My manifest.json file is

```
{
    "short_name": "Myapp",
    "name": "Myapp by vrpm",
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "favicon.ico",
            "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
            "type": "image/x-icon"
        }
    ],
    "start_url": ".",
    "display": "standalone",
    "theme_color": "#000000",
    "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

and my index.html is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Myapp</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
        <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=0, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1"
        />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" />
        <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
        <div id="root"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The NGINX configuration file looks as follows

```
worker_processes auto;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

http {

    include mime.types;

    upstream loadbalancer {
        server server:5000 weight=3;
    }

    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        server_name _;

        port_in_redirect off;
        absolute_redirect off;

        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen [::]:443 ssl;
        listen 443 ssl;

        server_name myapp.app* myapp.co* myapp-dev.uksouth.azurecontainer.io* localhost*;
        error_page 497 https://$host:$server_port$request_uri;

        error_log /var/log/nginx/client-proxy-error.log;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/client-proxy-access.log;

        ssl_protocols              TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers                ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-RC4-SHA:AES128:AES256:RC4-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;
        ssl_session_cache          shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_timeout        24h;

        keepalive_timeout 300;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains';

        ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/certificate.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/private.key;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

         location / {
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

         location /api/auth {
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://loadbalancer;
        }
        
        location /api/tours {
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://loadbalancer;
        }
    }
}
```

Locally, this configuration works fine and there is no suggestion that anything is wrong with my manifest.json or my index.html files. So the question I think must be:

**How can I ammend my NGINX proxying to allow for direct routing via the client using the url `myapp.com/tours/<some-id>`?**

---

Edit. Note, in my AuthRoute, I log the request path using the following code

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { AuthContext } from "../context/auth/authContext";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

const AuthRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
    const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);
    const { isAuthenticated, isAuthorizing } = authContext;
    
    console.log(`Navigation request for ${window.location.href}`);

    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={props =>
                !isAuthenticated && !isAuthorizing ? (<Redirect to="/login" />) : (<Component {...props} />)
            }
        />
    );
};
export default AuthRoute;
```

locally this prints out the requested route and it is navgated to; so

> Navigation request for https://localhost:3000/tours/3r4et66ksop093jsn

On Azure when deployed, these messages are never displayed which suggests that NGINX is intervieening.

---

I have implemented the suggested changes and my .config now looks like

```
worker_processes auto;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

http {

    include mime.types;

    upstream loadbalancer {
        server server:5000 weight=3;
    }

    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        server_name _;

        port_in_redirect off;
        absolute_redirect off;

        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen [::]:443 ssl;
        listen 443 ssl;

        server_name viewform.app* viewform.co* viewform-dev.uksouth.azurecontainer.io* localhost*;
        error_page 497 https://$host:$server_port$request_uri;

        error_log /var/log/nginx/client-proxy-error.log;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/client-proxy-access.log;

        ssl_protocols              TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers                ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-RC4-SHA:AES128:AES256:RC4-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;
        ssl_session_cache          shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_timeout        24h;

        keepalive_timeout 300;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains';

        ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/certificate.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/private.key;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        location /api/auth {
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://loadbalancer;
        }
        
        location /api/tours {
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://loadbalancer;
        }

        location / {
            try_files $uri /index.html;
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I navigate to dev.myapp/public/tours/ I get a blank page as shown below

[image]

with the following warnings

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
> manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.

My index.html and manifest.json is above.

Comment: the `index.html` file in nginx conf root location is from the app build?

Comment: @Chandan sorry for the delayed response. Yes it is. In the docker file this copy line is used `COPY --from=build /app/build/ /usr/share/nginx/html`

Comment: since nginx don't know about tours path and it is handled by react router you may need to add regex path and route all the request to `/` root location in nginx conf and may need to move the updated location below in nginx conf.

Comment: @MoonKnight The `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` message usually means you get some HTML page instead of JS file. Checking the actual response body can be helpful to trace the error.

Comment: Shouldn't your upstream server be localhost:5000, or ip:5000, instead of server:5000, just curious :) , is server any special word?

Comment: @RanuVijay It is a good question. What is not shown here is my server's Dockerfile, which names the service "server". When docker builds the image, it registers the service name with the OS and NGINX honours these "domain names" which is why you can and should use these names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nginx don't know about `tours` path which is handled by `react-router` you can either tell nginx to reroute all the request to `/` root route which then passes the request to `index.html` or you can add regex path and route all the request to `/` root location in `nginx.conf`. Since now `/` root location is handling all the other request may not get passed to other location so it would be best to move current route below static location in `nginx.conf`.

Below is how to route all request to `index.html` file
**nginx.conf**

```
...
location /api/auth {
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_pass http://loadbalancer;
}

location /api/tours {
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_pass http://loadbalancer;
}

location / {
     try_files $uri /index.html; # change as below
}
...
```

---

OP Edit: In my package.json "homepage": ".", needed to be "homepage": "/",. This is what was causing the routing to fail - sneaky. Hopefully this helps someone else.

Comment: Unfortunately, this has not helped, I get the same thing, a blank screen. I will drill into this a bit more this afternoon...

Comment: @MoonKnight have you tried without static route in `nginx.conf` and checked if static resources are loading.

Comment: @MoonKnight please try once more the updated answer if did'nt work then i try to make the same setup on my local

Comment: Now I get `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)` As even the api calls are being sent back to the client. I don't think this is right, I am going to dig and play around a bit now - thanks very much for your help here.

Comment: The strange this is mysite.com/home and /login get routed perfectly. /public/tours/<some id> fails.

Comment: @MoonKnight I have update the answer with fixed version there was issue with extra `/` slash at the end in `$url` now it will work I have tested locally in with this [`example`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start/2nd-example-nested-routing)

Comment: Again, I must thank you for your time here. I have tried this and updated the question with some further information. I am still merely getting a blank page...

Comment: Okay, so I found the issue! In my package.json `"homepage": ".",` needed to be `"homepage": "/",`. Now the tour/<id> routing works although I still have a seperate issue with public/tours/<id> but I think I can solve that.